# Django: Queryset distinct clause performance issue

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset, distinct

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a database query. Here are my models:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True)
```

---

```
class InformationSheet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='sheet')
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['latitude', 'longitude', 'owner']),
        ]
```

---

```
class Availability(models.Model):
   restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
   supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:
       indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['restaurant', 'supplier']),
        ]
```

I need to select InformationSheet between gps coordinates when restaurants availability is defined for given suppliers.

```
    suppliers = [1, 2, 3]
    sheets = InformationSheet.objects.filter(
        latitude__gte=lat_start,
        latitude__lte=lat_end,
        longitude__gte=long_min',
        longitude__lte=long_max,
        owner__availability__supplier_id__in=suppliers
    ).distinct()
```

The table has several hundred thousand entries.The SQL query generated was initially fast but adding the "distinct" clause to remove duplicates made the query too slow for my needs. Because the distinct prevents the use of indexes

How can I proceed?

Comment: I find this very strange, since these are all foreign keys, and by default Django sets indexes on foreign keys anyway. A `DISTINCT` has some impact, but this should be quite limited (it can simply store what is already enumerated).

Comment: With postgresql you can use `.distinct('distinct_field_name')` to only compare one field (usually your id) rather than entire rows. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added the query plan who looks okay... And i already tried to add only id field in distinct but the improvement isn't great. (about 10ms less)

Answer (score 0):

```
Limit  (cost=1.12..325.09 rows=30 width=215)
  ->  Unique  (cost=1.12..76866.65 rows=7118 width=215)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..76848.85 rows=7118 width=215)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..73308.59 rows=7118 width=219)
                    ->  Index Scan using restaurant_sheet_pkey on accommodation_sheet  (cost=0.42..12290.52 rows=193562 width=215)
                          Filter: ((latitude >= '-180.0000000'::numeric) AND (latitude <= 180.0000000) AND (longitude >= '-200.0000000'::numeric) AND (longitude <= 200.0000000))
                    ->  Index Only Scan using restaur_resta_i_3e16b7_idx on restaurant_availability  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=4)
                          Index Cond: (hotel_id = restaurant_sheet.owner_id)
                          Filter: (supplier_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))
              ->  Index Only Scan using restaurant_restaurant_pkey on restaurant_restaurant  (cost=0.42..0.50 rows=1 width=4)
                    Index Cond: (id = restaurant_sheet.owner_id)
```

In fact when looking at the query plan, the indexes are used I don't understand why it takes 500ms (with only a part of our database). I have an SSD as well as our development server.

I think I have badly designed the structure of the models but I don't really see how else to do it.